# ! LaTeX Error: \chapterformat undefined

Tags: miktex

After updating MikTex up to 09.04.2018 (MikTex 2.9.6637, Win 10, 64bit) I've got the error:

```
(F:\...\MiKTeX\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd)
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
! LaTeX Error: \chapterformat undefined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
l.29 \begin{document}
?
```

Maybe somebody knows how to fix it?

Sorry, my bad. This is MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\let\counterwithout\relax
\let\counterwithin\relax

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{interfaces-base}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=tex-text}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\end{document}
```

I use XeLatex and without

```
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}  
\setotherlanguage{english}                       
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=tex-text}
```

everything compile without errors.

Comment: As far as I can see, `\chapterformat` is defined in the Komascript classes. Which document class are you using?

Comment: @egereg I'm using extreport: \documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}

Comment: Show a complete minimal example.

Comment: @Alexey Then `\chapterformat` is not defined. That's all. Can you go to the third lane in a two lane motorway?

Comment: That is why you should always provide an example document, no one could guess from your question which document class you use. Also your wording implies that something changed after the update but `extreport` has never defined that command.

Comment: in a _minimal_ example it is intended that you delete every package that  you can delete while still showing the error. (You are asking people to trace a lot of code there....)

Comment: @egreg it's in tl2017

Comment: If you remove `interfaces-base`, the error disappears. The package is aimed to ease doing settings for various packages and you don't seem to be using its features. Avoid it.

Comment: Dear all, I've written to Florent Chervet (creator of interfaces.sty) and he said he renew package in a few months.

Answer (score 1):

The `interface-base` package should not be loaded alone, but accompanied by `\LoadInterface` instructions.

Just remove it, as you don't seem to be using its features (and it also appears to be buggy).

Comment: Unfortunately, I use some \LoadInterface instructions. Maybe you know how to fix  interface-base.sty?

Comment: @Alexey No. I don't use FC's packages and I don't recommend using them.

Comment: Ok. New version of polyglossia (08/04/2018) can't work with interface-base.sty